# working with rss + c#

Tags: c#, rss, dataset

Hi I'm trying to working with RSS feeds in C#. I added RSS feeds like

[this](http://cameras.shop.ebay.in/Digital-Cameras-/29997/i.html?_nkw=canon&_rss=1&_sop=1) 
and [this](http://www.amazon.com/rss/tag/blu-ray/new/ref=tag_rsh_hl_ersn_brp?%5Fencoding=UTF8&length=10)

When I try to read into a `DataSet` like:

```
 ds.readxml(rsspath)
```

I get some tables in a DataSet. Now how do I know which table contains exact data of all the products?

I'm not getting products list if I write:

`gv.datasource = ds.tables[0]`

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: I'm not gonna argue over this, but perhaps you're using the wrong tool for the job, and perhaps something else (XmlDocument and xpath was my route) is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

XmlDocument+ XPath or Linq2Xml should be a better way of handling the data

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [RSS.NET](http://www.rssdotnet.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is example code puts your RSS Feed into a collection of Syndication Items:

Using statements:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Xml;
```

Actual code:

```
string url = "http://www.amazon.com/rss/tag/blu-ray/new/ref=tag_rsh_hl_ersn_brp?%5Fencoding=UTF8&length=10";
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(url);
IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> items;
items = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader).Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes try Linq2Xml.  Here is an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx) that elaborates on both creating and consuming despite the title.