# Remove URl from a string in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a string I have parsed from a RSS feed

```
thumbnail url='http://photos3.media.pix.ie/11/C5/11C5B77C92204ADBBD0CF5FDF4BA351B-0000314357-    0002211156-00240L-00000000000000000000000000000000.jpg' height='240' width='226'
```

I need to remove just the URL detail from the string to form the basis of a image on a Windows Phone 7 application.

What would you suggest as the best way of doing this

The code from the phone is here

```
        FeedItems.ItemsSource = from imageFeed in xmlImageEntries.Descendants("item")
                                 select new PixIEPanoramaTest.Data.FeedItem
                                 {
                                     ThumbSource = imageFeed.Element("thumbnail").Value,

                                 };
```

Feeditems is just a bound list box. The thumbsource variable just needs the URL from the string.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated ,

Rob

Comment: So the result should be "11C5B77C92204ADBBD0CF5FDF4BA351B-0000314357-    0002211156-00240L-00000000000000000000000000000000.jpg" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just access the attribute value for the **url** attribute:

```
ThumbSource = imageFeed.Element("thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
```

It would probably worth using some kind of extensions method to return `string.Empty` if the attribute is missing, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries available to help parse RSS feeds - e.g.

- [working with rss + c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259392/working-with-rss-c)
- on codeplex http://rssr7.codeplex.com/releases/view/43832

If you want to do a quick "hacky" parse of the string yourself, then you could use RegularExpressions - e.g. a Regex something like `thumbnail url='(?<imageurl>http.*?)' height='240' width='226'` would pull out your url as the `imageurl` group

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"thumbnail url='(?<imageurl>http.*?)' height='240' width='226'");

if (match.Success)
{
    string url = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```